# Why is the Finder app always open?

Tags: finder, macos, application-switcher

First time Mac user. I am confused by the fact that the finder application is always open. For example, when switching apps with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it is always there, even when there are no windows opened for the app. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-tabbing to Finder with no windows/tabs opened for it has no effect (it seems to me it would more intuitive to open a new tab when this action is chosen).

Furthermore, there is no 'Close app' option when I right click the Finder icon in the dock. Am I misunderstanding something about the Finder app? Is it required for proper functioning of macOS? From what I see, Finder is just a file browser, which by no means should be forced to be open 100% of the time.

Comment: Check what happens when You click on Desktop:)

Comment: At first I didn't see anything, but I see now that the desktop in itself is a Finder window. Makes sense, just like with Gnome, etc.

Comment: See it as `explorer.exe` which is also always open on Windows

Comment: Thing is you don't see `explorer.exe` in Windows unless you open the task manager. It is there, but behind the scenes, you don't see it when alt-tabbing.

Comment: This is something you just get used to, coming from Windows. That Finder icon is always going to be in your Dock unless you try to do something really crazy. Don't. :]

Comment: @levesque That's actually not true. Since Windows 7 (almost 10 years now), "Desktop" has been included in the Alt-Tab list. That's explorer.exe.

Comment: Tell Voice Command/Siri to close Finder and see what happens.

Comment: you can quit finder by running the applescript:  `tell application "Finder" to quit`.  see what happens to the desktop!

Comment: @AndrewMedico wow, I really do not know Windows anymore. Been using Linux for work stuff, haven't looked back. There would still be a slight difference in behavior where alt-tabbing to desktop actually does something, whereas alt-tabbing to Finder without windows does nothing.

Comment: @dalearn Tried closing it, not much happens since my Desktop is blank ;)

Comment: @levesque Alt-tabbing to Finder does do something, just not everything it does in Windows. You are now in the Finder, and can do things like open up new finder windows, make folders on your desktop, and call "hide others", thus displaying the desktop.

Comment: @Logarr Good point.

Comment: @Andrew: The Desktop was removed from the Alt+Tab menu in Windows 10.

Comment: Its actually frustrating user experience. Even if you have no finder window open, while switching apps using cmd+tab, finder(without window) appears out of nowhere. It gives a feeling like sometimes cmd+tab work and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The main reason it's always open is that it displays the icons on the desktop. You can check what the finder does by enabling the "Quit" menu feature. To do this, launch the Terminal application and enter the following commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool YES
```

Hit return. Then restart the Finder by running

```
killall Finder
```

Close the Terminal. Click on the Desktop, choose "Finder" in the top bar, and "Quit Finder". Now you're running without Finder. First thing you'll notice is that all Desktop icons will be gone.

To get your desktop icons back, just click on Finder in the Dock.

If you want to remove the "Quit Finder" menu item, you can do that with:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool NO
```

Comment: Another way to quit Finder (without it automatically reopening) is to open Script editor and type `Tell application "Finder" to quit`. For some reason, when the command comes from Applescript, Finder will oblige.

Answer (score 18):

It's not only a "file browser", but it's responsible for quite a bit of GUI functionality such as the Desktop, following paths and connecting to servers. Finder is always running, and a launch service will relaunch it if it is quit unnaturally. Much like File Explorer (explorer.exe) on Windows, you shouldn't quit it. Quit functionality can be added back to Finder, but you really shouldn't unless you have a very good reason for it.

Comment: Actually, Finder is not auto-relaunched, regardless of the `QuitMenuItem` setting.  I've observed this in 10.9 through 10.12.

Comment: Haha, I find myself quitting explorer.exe quite often XD I find my way around without the GUI fairly easily since clthe command prompt can still be used

Comment: *Quit functionality can be added back to Finder, but you really shouldn't* Why not? Aside from the GUI functions, no part of the system depends on the Finder. IMO the Finder *is* just a file browser -- the GUI functionality of displaying icons on the desktop is just one of the functions of that file browser.

Comment: @Bob Finder is restarted "if it is quit unnaturally"

Answer (score 5):

Think of the background process for Finder akin to that of the 'Windows Explorer' background process on Windows.  As mentioned above, it is essential for the MacOS UI & GUI elements on the desktop.  If you are new to Mac, take a look at the Activity Monitor App in your Utilities folder.  This is essentially the Mac equivalent to Task Manager on Windows and can help organize/debug processes in the background.